AWS RDS MySQL | Unable to launch snapshot in cluster mode
I am unable to launch an existing snapshot(300GB, having around 1000 schemas) into an MySql MultiAZ Cluster v8.0.36.
Please find stats for the same Image:
SingleAZ (1 node)  8GB   Launching Successfully
MultiAZ (2 nodes)  8GB   Launching Successfully
Cluster (3 nodes)  8GB   Unable to launch
Cluster (3 nodes)  16GB  Unable to launch
Cluster (3 nodes)  32GB  Launching Successfully.
Cluster (3 nodes)  32GB  Unable to launch on upgrading to v8.0.39
Cluster (3 nodes)  8GB   Unable to launch if RAM is lowered back to 8GB]
Further, AWS support is not able to give any useful insights since long.
We wanted to utilize the Master & ReaderEndpoints of a MySql Cluster to optimize the frequent reads. However, this often fails if going in the Cluster (3) nodes and takes much more time as compared to 1/2 nodes.

Is there some known issue with MySql Cluster on AWS RDS?
How can I debug more.

